# How to clone ImageAd and ResponsiveDisplayAd

Tags: php, google-ads-api

We need to update `finalUrls` of all the ads we have. We have several hundred `ImageAd` and `ResponsiveDisplayAd`s and we don't want to lose the existing configuration and/or images. As Google doesn't allow us to update any property of a `AdGroupAd` apart from status, we will have to clone them using `ADD` operator.

While doing this we get several errors and all of them are related to `ad.image`. What's the correct/best way to go about these updates?

`[AdError.IMAGE_ERROR @ operations[0].operand.ad]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I found out from little googling that `adToCopyImageFrom` is what I had to use in order to copy over image properties of an ad (`ImageAd` only!) in order to clone. So, if `$currentAd` is the `AdGroupAd` object containing your existing `ImageAd` and you are trying to create a new one `$newAd` and want to copy over images, here is what you can do (not sure if this is the best way but worked well for me!):

```
$newAd = new ImageAd();
$newAd = $ad->ad;
// Let Google do the image copying
// Remember $currentAd is a AdGroupAd and not an Ad
$newAd->adToCopyImageFrom = $currentAd->ad->id;
$newAd->id = null;
$newAd->image = null;
```

Similarly, for `ResponsiveDisplayAd`, here is what I did:

```
$newRespAd = new ResponsiveDisplayAd();
// Make sure you included MediaId while fetching
// $currentRespAd
$newRespAd = $currentRespAd->ad;
$newRespAd->id = null;
```